# Открытие файлов сторонними программами

Tags: c#, winapi, файлы

Добрый вечер. 
Как реализовывается или, хотя бы, называется способ, который позволяет из твоего приложения, вызвать стандартный "Открыть с помощью" и уже передать дело винде?

То есть, к примеру, у меня есть список файлов в приложении, и при клике на изображении, надо чтобы оно передавалось Просмоторщику фотографий Windows или любому другому приложению по-умолчанию. Причем не через api каждого приложения, а через winapi. 
Есть ли вообще такая возможность?

Помогите сформулировать вопрос)

Спасибо.

Comment: @VladD , ответьте на вопрос, чтобы я засчитал это)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) умеет запускать не только исполнимые файлы, но и документы в соответствии с зарегистрированным типом.

Например,

```
Process.Start("picture.jpg");
```

запустит просмотрщик картинок по умолчанию, как если бы пользователь выбрал этот элемент в Проводнике.

Comment: Благодарю. Решение оказалось на много проще, чем я думал.

Comment: @Эмиль: не за что!